# Prove $A-B$ is invertible given that $A^2=A$ and $2A-B-AB = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $A^2 = A, 2A − B − AB = I$,

- (i) prove that $A − B$ is invertible;
- (ii) if $A =
  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 3 & −1\\
  0 & 6 & −2\end{bmatrix}$, find $B$.

I have no directions doing this, because I cannot get $A-B$ from the equation given.  I can only get nothing related.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. . Here's a hint:  what's $(A+I)(A-B)$?

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and how I edited your question to learn how to properly typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Thank you..........

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks a lot, it really works. But i wonder how did you get the term (A+I), is there any special method to get this term? A+I is the inverse of A-B, and the method i learnt at school to get inverse is to use augmented matrix, however, this method doesn't work if i don't have the numbers/ any thing about the shape of the matrix

Comment: I just recognized that $I=2A-B-AB=A^2+A-B-AB=$ $(A+I)A-(A+I)B=$ $(A+I)(A-B)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oh i see thank you

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks! i will take a look

Answer (score 1):

For (i), J.W. Tanner gives you a hint.

For (ii): multiply $2A − B − AB = I$ from the right with $A$. Then you should derive $AB=\frac{1}{2}A.$

Now use again $2A − B − AB = I$ to obtain $B= .... $.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps another method i got from W.Tanner's hint is that , since the inverse of (A-B) is (A+I), and in turn the inverse of (A+I) is (A-B), since we can get A+I as the value of A is given, we can get A-B, so i can get B